# Floating horizontal scroll bar for html table

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, asp.net-mvc, telerik-mvc

I have an html table that is very tall.  The web page has to be scrolled vertically to reach the scroll bar at the bottom of the table.  It would be nice if I could float the horizontal scroll bar for the table at the bottom of the browser window while the user is scrolling the page and the table is visible.  Can such a thing be done?

Here is a jsFiddle example of the situation: http://jsfiddle.net/RurTZ/1/

Comment: Look at http://www.matts411.com/post/super_tables/ and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12075757/floating-horizontal-scroll-bar-for-html-table

Comment: It's not very helpful for the question, but it's good practice to avoid horizontal scrolling. It really bugs users.

Comment: could you show us some code? should be easy with plain css and html, but depends a bit on the situation... A fiddle would be even better!

Comment: I added the fiddle to the question

Comment: @Alex I have the same question now, the table sometimes is pretty big vertically, so I don't want user to scroll to the bottom then scroll left and right. Rather have a horizontal scroll bar always at the bottom of the screen. How did you solve your problem?

Comment: @Princa I didn't, but I came close.  Because I was using a third party grid with all kinds of rigid rendering of headers, footers, and other fancy stuff it was really difficult to account for all conditions and browser cross-compatibility.

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/24552684/1183010

Answer (score 4):

The [Grid](http://www.matts411.com/post/grid/) suggestion by @KDavid is good, but if you're looking for something a bit lighter I had success with the the [floatingScrollbar jQuery plugin](https://gist.github.com/cowboy/846423) ([demo](http://bit.ly/12v0Nx0)).

After making sure the plugin JS is loaded, the magic call happens:

```
$('.your-div').floatingScrollbar();
```

I also had to set the div CSS to:

```
.your-div {
  overflow-x: auto;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Here is a fork of your jsFiddle with it working: http://jsfiddle.net/RxTQM/1/

Answer (score 2):

Yes, place it inside a `<div>` tag, and add `overflow:scroll;` to the style of the div.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work.  I have the table `height: 100%` and the wrapping div `overflow: scroll` but the scrollbar only appears at the very bottom of the table

Comment: As Alex mentioned, this is the right answer for getting a horizontal scrollbar (and in this case the vertical scroll too potentially), but it doesn't address the real question which is how to make that horizontal scrollbar float.