# How to install a jQuery Plugin in Ionic and Angular

Tags: jquery, angular, ionic3

I am using Ionic 3/Angular 5 am trying to setup a floating horizontal scroll bar for a very tall table in a component. I have come across this solution which should work nicely: [Floating horizontal scroll bar for html table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12075757/floating-horizontal-scroll-bar-for-html-table)

http://jsfiddle.net/cowboy/45rEs/show/

The issue is I have trouble importing the jQuery function into my component.

So far I have successfully installed jQuery and it is working correctly. Furthermore I have imported the jQuery plugin into my index:

```
<script src="assets/jquery.ba-floatingscrollbar.min.js"></script>
```

How do I include it in my component? Currently I get an error:

> Property 'floatingScrollbar' does not exist on type 'JQuery'

**Component**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import * as $ from 'jquery';
@Component({
  selector: 'tall-table',
  templateUrl: 'tall-table.html'
})
export class TallTableComponent {

  constructor() {
  }

  ngAfterViewInit(): void { 
    $('#horz-scroll-wrapper').floatingScrollbar();
  }

}
```

**tall-table.html**

```
<div id="horz-scroll-wrapper" style="width: 300px; overflow: scroll">
    <div style="height: 100%;">
        <table class='sample'>
            <tbody>
                <tr *ngFor="let row of [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26]">
                    <td >abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</td><td >ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ</td><td >1234567890</td><td >0987654321</td><td >abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</td><td >ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ</td><td >1234567890</td><td >0987654321</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried it within chrome's console?  I would try that first to see if its your import that is the issue or something else...

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed jQuery global derectory to typings?

```
npm install @types/jquery
```

Comment: Yes I have installed types for Jquery. But I think I need to create a type file for the actual floatingbar plugin but not sure how

Comment: I'm not sure you need that as you are already using jquery to access the dom & your script will already have been loaded if you can find it in your dom (you should check this using chrome dev tools).  Off the top of my head have you tried $(this.nativeElement).find('#horz-scroll-wrapper')?  This would be a more angular way of doing things anyway as you are no longer accessing the entire dom within your component.